# How to display the quiz title with the number of users in each quiz in ASP.NET chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-charts

I am creating a quiz maker in my web application. The database consists of the following tables:

- QUIZ Table: QuizID, Title, Description
- UserQuiz Table: UserQuizID, QuizID, DateTimeComplete, Score, Username

Now, I want to develop a chart the shows the title of quiz with the number of users who took each one of these quizzes, but I don't know how. I am trying to get a good query for this but I don't know how.

I am using SqlDataSource for accessing the data in the database.

Please help me.

Comment: In SQL? In a particular ORM framework? How are you accessing the data?

Comment: I am using .NET Framework 4.0 (ASP.NET webforms) and Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL this would be something like

```
SELECT  Q.QuizID, Q.Title, count(uq.*) as Users
  FROM  UserQuiz UQ
  JOIN  Quiz Q ON Q.QuizID = UQ.QuizID
GROUP BY Q.QuizID, Q.Title
```

or without the table aliases `Q` and `UQ` this would be

```
SELECT  Quiz.QuizID, Title, count(*) as Users
  FROM  UserQuiz
  JOIN  Quiz ON Quiz.QuizID = UserQuiz.QuizID
GROUP BY Quiz.QuizID, Title
```

using the full table names to distinguish between the two columns called QuizID.

Comment: Could you please simplify your query? I did not understand it especially the letters Q, UQ, uq.*

Comment: They're alias table names: `FROM UserQuiz UQ` means use `UQ` as an alias for `UserQuiz` and likewise `Q` for `Quiz`. You need aliases to distinguish between the two columns called because you have a column called QuizID in each table.

Answer (score 1):

How about trying something like this

```
SELECT Title, count(UserQuizID) as usercount
FROM quiz a
JOIN userquiz b on a.quizid = b.quizid
GROUP BY Title
```

Title would be your `XValueMember` and usercount `YValueMember` for the series.

Comment: I tried to execute this query in SQLServer Management Studio, but I got an error. I don't know why

Comment: @Rup Indeed should be .. my bad